# Resources for Large Groups

Tags: dnd-5e, system-introduction, session

We're starting an offline gaming club here at the school I teach at. I'll probably lead a few D&D 5e sessions to get things started and I thought it might be a good idea to get some input from experienced DMs/players here. I played D&D back in the 1980s but I've not DMd before and am just catching up to 5e rules and how the game has evolved.

My ideas on how to run these sessions so far:

- instead of a long campaign, run sessions that can be concluded in a single 3-4 hour sitting
- they need to be scaleable sessions that will stay balanced regardless of how many people show up
- sessions need to be accessible to anyone who rocks up out of curiosity and interesting enough for people with some experience with the RPG format
- sessions should include combat, role playing, character development, opportunities to use the proficiencies of each class so that players can learn how the game works
- sessions should serve as an introduction to the game to entice students to run their own campaigns

I want the sessions to work as I've described, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm going to cut-and-paste some things from http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/74672/23970 and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65682/23970, along with some unique-to-this-question thoughts to cobble together an answer. But feel free to poke around until that comes along. I run a similar club at my school and also took a multi-decade hiatus before jumping back into 5e!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. Idea-generation questions don't really work in the Stack Exchange site format. As a rule they result in a list of ideas with [no obvious way for voters to tell which answers are better than others](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This would need to be revised to be about solving a *specific* concrete problem to be answerable in our Q&A site format. Otherwise, you may just actually want an [RPG discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack.

Comment: One of the venues you'd find if you followed @SSD's link to forums would be [chat]--you can come by any time and once you've got 20 reputation you'll be able to join in the conversation.

Comment: I'm trying to drill down to the core of an answerable question here, and I'm ending up at "[5e] how do I run 3-4hr sessions for a drop-in style group of varying experience while maintaining the trifecta of combat, roleplay, exploration?" Does that sound right?

Comment: @nitsua60 , It's a huge question actually, isn't it? I think I should break it into smaller ones and ask them on a priority basis. I really appreciate the immediate response here though and would like to keep in touch to see how your club dealt with inherent issues.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie. yup. sorry. I use stack overflow extensively so I should have known better. My bad. Thanks for the informed response.

Comment: @ekendra No problem! (I've done the same thing when first asking on an unfamiliar stack, myself.) You could also take both routes: copy the original of this into an RPG forum/chat to have a roundtable discussion, and simultaneously pare this down to a pointed problem post (or three) that could be solved here—tackling it in two different paradigms. :)

Comment: @ekendra you should definitely pop into chat, then--I'd be glad to share the experiences I've had with my high-school kids.

Comment: @nitsua60 I popped over but not enough rep to participate. oh well. Someone love me or something so I can transcend these confines.