# What books are needed to play D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players

I am new to D&D and haven't even played the game. In fact, I haven't bought anything at all!

If I were to buy the newest D&D starter set (the one with the green dragon on the front, I think it's the 5th edition), is there anything else I would need to buy?

From the starter set I would already have...

- 5 ready to play characters
- 6 die
- One Adventure book: Lost Mine of Phandelver
- One rulebook
- One character sheet

Comment: related (see listing at right, where they'll appear by name): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11033/23970, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108581/23970

Comment: Is your question “what do I need to play?”, or is your question, “if I buy the Starter Set, do I need anything else to play?”?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start playing DnD 5e, you **don't have to** buy anything at all! (Except dice!<sup>*</sup>)

In fact, there is freely available [Basic Rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63297/is-it-necessary-to-purchase-all-the-dd-5th-edition-books-to-have-access-to-all) that you can study to learn more about the game! This covers the most basic stuffs for players and DMs. [More books](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63297/is-it-necessary-to-purchase-all-the-dd-5th-edition-books-to-have-access-to-all) are available to expand your character choices and variant rules. As a DM, [Monster Manual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm) is available to further expand the choices of monsters to throw at your opponent.

[Character sheet PDF](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/character_sheets) is available to download.

The reason why me and my friends get hooked into DnD so quickly is you can start a session with the bare minimum of character sheets and dice. Of course, you need a DM that has already learned the basic rules!

As a DM, you might want to enhance the play using a map, printed or handdrawn, and token/miniatures for the player characters and monsters, but again, this is **not** a necessity to start playing DnD.

<sup>*</sup>You can replace physical dice with a dice roller app, but nothing beat the feeling of rolling *real* dice.

---

The Starter Set materials contain exactly what you need to start an adventure with your party!

1. You have **5 pregenerated character sheets**, meaning you don't have to go through the hassle of creating new characters. Just start the adventure already!
   Another **blank sheet** is available if you want to create your dream character, just make sure you have blank copies!
2. **6 *perfect* dice**, just pray to RNGods before you start rolling 'em!
3. **Lost Mine of Phandelver adventure book**, the best book ever, for beginner and veteran players. Easy to run for players and DM alike.
4. **Basic Rules**. Read-me-first, but don't be afraid to make up your ruling if you forget me!

(bring your own pencil, sharpener, and eraser, please!)

Comment: Maybe mention how these fit into/expand on the limitations of the Starter Set’s materials?